# Find and update a numbering in a html file with awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I am trying to update a numbering/numeration in a test.html file:

```
<td class="no">(8)</td>
<td class="no">(9)</td>
<td class="no">(10)</td>
<td class="no">(11)</td>
<td class="no">(23)</td>
```

A new line could be added between the other lines, so I don't want to update the numeration always manually. Another condition is, that the update should start after number 7.

I tried to use gensub by replacing the line by the match but it doesn't work how I thought. There must be an easier way to determine the numbers! No tutorials or forum posts did help me or I didn't understand them...

So far what I have:

```
/^<td class="no">\([0-9]+\)<\/td>$/ {
  a = gensub(/(.*)([0-9]+)(.*)/, "\\2", "g") # this finds only 1 digit, why?
  if (a > 7) print a
}
```

Comment: The answer to you `why` is that `.` in `.*` matches digits too. In any case, you can apply the answer given at http://stackoverflow.com/a/40512703/1745001 to this problem. See in particular the simplified gawk-specific solution for non-nested terminators at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to `determine the numbers`, you only must get rid of any character not being a digit

```
/^<td class="no">\([0-9]+\)<\/td>$/ {
  gsub("[^0-9]","")
  if ((0+$0) > 7) print
}
```

**update**: **`(0+$0) > 7`** replaces my original **`$0 > 7`** because the **cygwing gawk** does not compare `$0` and `7` as numerical values but as string values --- I do not know why. I'm not familiar with **cygwin**.

This solution prints the following output:

```
8
9
10
11
23
```

If the `test.html` file had contained a line like

```
<td class="no">(71)</td>
```

the original code (`$0 > 7`) would have also print

```
71
```

in cygwin.

Comment: This prints only 8 and 9 into the console. I am using Cygwin on Windows.

Comment: @SananeLan, my code prints the numbers inside the brakets when it is greater than 7. What do you code prints out?

Comment: well as I said, only the the lines where 8 and 9 are in brakets. Does your code also print out the numbers with 2 digits?

Comment: @SananeLan, yes it does. It prints any number greater than 7. Have you tried my code?

Comment: I used only your code, and I tried it with a test.html file containing <td class="no">(8)</td> to <td class="no">(12)</td> and it prints only 8 and 9 into the console. I used it like: gawk -f listnums.awk test.html. I tried it with cygwin and mingw, same result.

Comment: Please, can you post the test.html file used?

Comment: I edited my question. (I don't seem to be able to use [at]user, it disappears after posting a comment, or maybe I just can't see it?)

Comment: @SananeLan, I edited my solution. I cannot explain why cygwin gawk behaves different than RedHat or CentOS gawk.

Comment: yes you are right, now it works. I neither know why cygwin behaves like that, and I've no experience with (g)awk, so I couldn't think of that...