# Find and replace URL with content from URL

Tags: bash, loops, url, awk, sed

**Background info:**
I've got an XML file that my supplier uploads each night with new products and updated stock counts etc.
But they've stitched me up and they don't have a Description in the XML file, they have a link to their site which has the description in raw text.

What i need to do is have a script that loops through the document i download from them and replace the URL with the content of the URL.

For example, if i have

```
<DescriptionLink>http://www.leadersystems.com.au/DataFeed/ProductDetails/AT-CHARGERSTATION-45</DescriptionLink>
```

I want it to end up as

```
<DescriptionLink>Astrotek USB Charging Station Charger Hub 3 Port 5V 4A with 1.5m Power Cable White for iPhone Samsung iPad Tablet GPS</DescriptionLink>
```

I've tried a few things but i'm not very proficient with scripting or loops.
So far i've got:

```
#!/bin/bash
LINKGET=`awk -F '|' '{ print $2 }' products-daily.txt`

wget -O products-daily.txt http://www.suppliers-site-url.com
sed 's/<DescriptionLink>*/<DescriptionLink>$(wget -S -O- $LINKGET/g' products-daily.txt
```

But again, i'm not sure how this all really works so it's been trial and error.
Any help is appreciated!!!

Updated to include example URL.

Comment: Could you provide an url example? Otherwise it is difficult to test...

Comment: Added URL for example :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want something like this (using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match()):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    head = ""
    tail = encode($0)
    while ( match(tail,/^([^{]*[{])([^}]+)(.*)/,a) ) {
        desc = ""
        cmd = "curl -s \047" a[2] "\047"
        while ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
            desc = (desc=="" ? "" : desc ORS) line
        }
        close(cmd)
        head = head decode(a[1]) desc
        tail = a[3]
    }
    print head decode(tail)
}
function encode(str) {
    gsub(/@/,"@A",str)
    gsub(/{/,"@B",str)
    gsub(/}/,"@C",str)
    gsub(/<DescriptionLink>/,"{",str)
    gsub(/<\/DescriptionLink>/,"}",str)
    return str
}
function decode(str) {
    gsub(/}/,"</DescriptionLink>",str)
    gsub(/{/,"<DescriptionLink>",str)
    gsub(/@C/,"}",str)
    gsub(/@B/,"{",str)
    gsub(/@A/,"@",str)
    return str
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
<DescriptionLink>Astrotek USB Charging Station Charger Hub 3 Port 5V 4A with 1.5m Power Cable White for iPhone Samsung iPad Tablet GPS</DescriptionLink>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40512703/1745001 for info on what the encode/decode functions are doing and why.

Note that this is one of the rare cases where use of `getline` is appropriate. If you're ever considering using `getline` in future make sure you read and fully understand all of the caveats and uses cases discussed at http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline first.

Comment: When running this command on the 5000+ entries i have in my file i get an error saying ``fatal: cannot open pipe `curl -s (Too many open files)``
Any idea's Ed?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to close the pipe after each call like it shows you in that article I referenced at the bottom of my answer (see `a) Reading from a pipe` in it). Fixed now.